# Is my Http API accessible when setting it after AWS API gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I set an api gateway for my private rest api, my question is: if anyone have the url of my private api can he access it?
and if there is a good way to test such scenarios?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iS5Vc.png)

In the Attached image if someone has the url http://myDomain/get-one can he access my server?
if yes what is the solution? could we add IP address to api gateway and in my server only accepts request from this IP address

Comment: Private API is not accessible from the internet - thus its name.

Comment: You can put your server inside a private subnet in the VPC, not accessible from the outside, reaching it only with the API gateway